# Running two websites on the same server with the same SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, iis, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have created two sites on my server, on different subdomains. I have a SSL certificate I am binding to website A, running without problems. When I add binding to the same certificate on website B, it fails to run, saying

"This website cannot be started. Another web site may be using the same port."

When I remove the binding to :443 from website B and just leave http running at :80, it starts without problems (website A's http is also running on :443). What could be the problem?

Note: apparantely, the reason why both A nd B are capable of running on :80 is that they are also bound to different subdomains - however, the textbox for inputting website-specific subdomains is disabled when adding a binding to an SSL certificate.

Comment: According to this guide it is possible http://www.sherweb.com/blog/host-different-ssls-on-one-ip-with-iis-8-sni/

Comment: Thanks. Too bad I'm running IIS 6...

Comment: IIS6? Do you mean that you are still using Windows Server 2003?